# Translating SQL to lambda with groupby

Tags: c#, sql, lambda, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to translate this sql statement

```
SELECT row, SUM(value) as VarSum, AVG(value) as VarAve, COUNT(value) as TotalCount 
FROM MDNumeric
WHERE collectionid = 6 and varname in ('C3INEV1', 'C3INEVA2', 'C3INEVA3', 'C3INVA11', 'C3INVA17', 'C3INVA19')
GROUP BY row
```

into an EF 4 query using lambda expressions and am missing something.

I have:

```
sumvars = sv.staticvararraylist.Split(',');

var aavresult = _myIFR.MDNumerics
    .Where(r => r.collectionid == _collid)
    .Where(r => sumvars.Contains(r.varname))
    .GroupBy(r1 =>r1.row)
    .Select(rg =>
          new
          {
              Row = rg.Key,
              VarSum = rg.Sum(p => p.value),
              VarAve = rg.Average(p => p.value),
              TotalCount = rg.Count()
          });
```

where the staticvararraylist has the string 'C3INEV1', 'C3INEVA2', 'C3INEVA3', 'C3INVA11', 'C3INVA17', 'C3INVA19' (without single quotes) and the _collid variable = 6.

While I'm getting the correct grouping, my sum, average, & count values aren't correct.

Comment: What is the Type of `row`?  Does it implement `IEquatable<T>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't post your error message, but I suspect it's related to `Contains`. I've found that `Any` works just as well.

This should get you quite close:

```
var result =
    from  i in _myIFR.MDNumerics
    where i.collectionid == _collid && sumvars.Any(v => i.varname == v)
    group i by i.row into g
    select new {
        row = g.Key,
        VarSum = g.Sum(p => p.value),
        VarAve = g.Average(p => p.value),
        TotalCount = g.Count()
    };
```

Comment: Not getting any error, the problem is the results set calculations aren't correct. For example for the records where row = 1 the SQL statement gives me VarSum = 30, VarAve= 5, TotalCount = 6.  The result set from both this and Fabrice's lambda version give VarSum=5, VarAve = 5.0, and TotalCount = 1.  (I'm assuming the 's.Sum' in the select new is 'g.Sum').  It looks like it isn't summing all the records.  There are several records in the table that have the same value in the 'row' field and I'm trying to pull statistics based on all the related row values.

Comment: The data from the table where row = 1 includes these records:/row Total Average Count / 
1 5 5 5 /
1 5 5 5 /
1 5 5 5 /
1 5 5 5 /
1 5 5 5 /
1 5 5 5 /

Comment: @DeeDub84, do you have a unique id for each item you're working with? If not, you may find that rows are being excluded from select statement when using entity framework, depending upon how you're using it. At any rate, I don't think there's enough information in your question to know how to help you.

Comment: I'm thinking that the problem is in the .Contains or .Any.  It is only selecting table rows that match the first item in the list, not table rows that match any of the items.  Currently sumvars is a string[] which is filled by the sumvars = sv.staticvararraylist which is a field with a comma delimited list. I want to select rows where the varname is in the list in sumvars. Something must be wrong though.

Comment: May I suggest you try experimenting with LINQpad. It understands EF and will show you the SQL that it's generating for a given LINQ-to-Entities expression.

Comment: As it turns out, the string used to fill the sumvars array had spaces included before the commas, so it was only picking up the first one in the list... Can't believe how much time went down the tubes on this one.

Comment: @DeeDub84, it happens. The main thing is that you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var aavresult = _myIFR.MDNumerics
.Where(r => r.collectionid == _collid && sumvars.Contains(r.varname))
.GroupBy(r1 =>r1.row,
  (key,res) =>    new
      {
          Row = key,
          VarSum = res.Sum(r1 => r1.value),
          VarAve = res.Average(r1 => r1.value),
          TotalCount = res.Count()
      });
```

Comment: Fabrice, see my comment to Drew.  The results set isn't summing / averaging / counting all the records.